How do i access my pysimplegui program online?
I made a program using Pysimplegui, but I want to access it over the internet.  I found pysimpleguiweb which looked promising, except it looks like it is still version 0.39, so it isn't finished?  I would like to know where instructions are for this.
The below is a website which looks like someone is still working on it as of two weeks ago, but it also looks like they're asking for payment.
https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/142
Below may be the answer, it looks like they're creating a pysimplgui and then using flask to show it over the internet.  Will Django do the same thing?  I can't find much on the internet about django and pysimplegui, or flask and pysimplegui.
how to send data from separate computer to flask app
Is there a way to access my pysimplegui program over the internet?
